# Facebook php-sdk link wall post is not good

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

first ask for permission:

```
if(!$data["user_id"]) {

  $app_id = "175403625997298";

    $redirect_url = urlencode("https://www.facebook.com/szalagavatoszeged/app_175403625997298?app_data=haho"); 
    $scope = "publish_stream";
    $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_url . "&scope=" . $scope;
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    $login_url=$facebook->getLoginUrl($scope);
    fb_publish();
}
```

After checking the arguments that I gave in the link:

```
if($szavazott=='haho'){
    header('Location: szavazott.php');

}
```

and post:

```
try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
    array('link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/szalagavatoszeged/app_175403625997298','message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!',));

    print 'haha';

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

}
```

But this code not posting:S What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have errors enabled in php, that you can catch and print the array here for us? 

<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

Comment: You're silently trapping and discarding exceptions. I'd start there.

Comment: You really should not give out your app id...

Comment: the app is safe to publish, no big deal. only the app secret should be kept...well, secret ;)

Comment: Yep, App ID is public anyway. You can see it on facebook and in the JavaScript source code easily. Also, if you're using the Facebook SDK, why are you manually building a login URL. Just use $facebook->getLoginUrl().